# how to get a random value from one array to another in java

Tags: java, arrays, random, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to get a random array value from `char[] vowel` and `char[] consonant` into `char[] firstName` and `char[] lastName`.

My IDE (Eclipse) shows no errors for

`firstName[i]=consonant [random.nextInt(consonant.length)];`

however when running the code I'll get the error

> ```
> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> 0     at _01NameGenerator.main(_01NameGenerator.java:27)`
> ```

How shall I fix this statement?

```
// http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62
import java.util.Random;

public class _001NameGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int firstNameLength = 7; // fixed length, not "random"
        int lastNameLength = 5;  

        System.out.println("Your firstname will be "+firstNameLength+" and you lastname "+lastNameLength+" characters long.");

        char[] vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};      
        char[] consonant = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z'};

        char[] firstName = new char[firstNameLength];
        char[] lastName = new char[lastNameLength];


        boolean wechsel = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < firstNameLength; i++) {

            if (wechsel == true){

                firstName[i]=consonant [random.nextInt(20)];  // length of consonant array
                wechsel = false;

            } else {

                firstName[i]=vowel [random.nextInt(6)]; // length of vowel array
                wechsel = true;
            }

        }   

        for (int i = 0; i < lastNameLength; i++) {

            if (wechsel == true){

                lastName[i]=consonant [random.nextInt(20)];
                wechsel = false;

            } else {

                lastName[i]=vowel [random.nextInt(6)];
                wechsel = true;
            }

        }   

        System.out.println(firstName + "\n" + lastName);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `char[] someArray = {};` does, and why do you think you can use it in a way `someArray[0]`? Do you know that arrays have fixed length?

Comment: Hi pshemo, I did not know about the fixed length. I just wanted it to be initialised. However giving it the length of `firstNameLenght` unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Comment: Actually it solves this problem, but apparently you have another one. So what is the error message now?

Comment: Either `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at _01NameGenerator.main(_01NameGenerator.java:27)` or `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at _01NameGenerator.main(_01NameGenerator.java:32)`

Comment: It means that your loop is trying to access elements outside of array bound. Try to limit range of `[i]` and `[random.nextInt(consonant.length)]` properly (use length of proper array).

Comment: Can you update the code to match what you're running now? Right now I still see `firstName` being initialized to `{}`

Comment: I updated the code. I removed the random factor and tried a fixed value due the suggestion. The programm output is always `Your firstname will be 7 and you lastname 5 characters long.
[C@15db9742
[C@6d06d69c`
Thanks for you commitment

Comment: @grerrg The code as currently written doesn't throw any exceptions. What problem do you have with the code as it stands?

Comment: @cary m Well the program always generates `[C@15db9742 [C@6d06d69c` as names. Tough numbers and `@` are not in the consonant and vowel array.

Comment: @grerrg What you're seeing is how Java renders as a String. Whether it's an array of `char`s, `int`s or `Object`s it's going to look like that. 
Sound like what you want here is to convert the array of chars to a String, which you can by replacing `firstName` with `new String(firstName)`.

Comment: @cary m thanks to the suggestion with `new String(firstName)`. The program runs like I want it to.

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] firstName = {};
char[] lastName = {};
```

These two lines generate empty lists, so whenever you try to add something it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`.

Since you have the random length above, try this instead:

```
char[] firstName = new char[firstNameLength];
char[] lastName = new char[lastNameLength];
```

Also, in case you wouldn't have known the length of the arrays beforehand, you can use an ArrayList, which are created for these kind of purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion with `char[] firstName = new char[firstNameLength];`. The array has now the right length. But I get the same error. I will check the code more attentively

Comment: @grerrg I've tried your edited code of your main post, and it seems to work without errors now. The only thing left to add is the char-array to String in the print-line. You can do this by changing your print to `System.out.println(new String(firstName) + "\n" + new String(lastName));` [Here is the ideone.](http://ideone.com/cl26CS)

Answer (score 1):

You've initialized `firstName` and `lastName` as zero-length arrays. So on your first iteration, you try to assigned a value to `firstName[0]`, but "0" is an invalid index for an empty array, hence the exception.

You should initialize the arrays with lengths:

```
char[] firstName = new char[firstNameLength];
char[] lastName = new char[lastNameLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious: both of these arrays are zero length:

```
    char[] firstName = {};
    char[] lastName = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `firstName` and `lastName` arrays as an empty zero-length arrays. You should declare as follows according to your code:

```
char[] firstName = new char[firstNameLength];
char[] lastName = new char[lastNameLength];
```

This prevent you from getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.